# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter application keeps on crashing and logging this error on firebase crash analytics

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.aims.covidsurvey/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter activity
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4463)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4482)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1640)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Have tried to debug the app, am not getting much information what is causing the error, anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it? Have tried to research am not getting much information

the Kotlin code generated by the app

```
package com.example.app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

And another crash error

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter activity
       at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.setActivity(FlutterLocationService.kt)
       at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.deinitialize(LocationPlugin.java:121)
       at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity(LocationPlugin.java:56)
       at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity(LocationPlugin.java:69)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.detachFromActivity(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:389)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:556)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.release(FlutterActivity.java:587)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy(FlutterActivity.java:608)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7136)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4450)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4482)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1640)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: I have the same problem here ... any solution?

Comment: Hi @Iams no solution, still searching

Comment: My solution was to change the component location to geolocator https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: Same solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the component location to geolocator
https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator